# Change header of csv file

Tags: python

I'm developing a software that generate some signals with this parameters as input : `('Name', minValue, maxValue)`.

This data will compose a csv file. The header of csv file will be like that : `["Name", "ValueS1", "ValueS2"]`

This header presumes that I have 2 signals. If I want to have 3 or 4 signals, how can I do to change automatically my header to get the header like that `["Name", "ValueS1", "ValueS2", "ValueS3", "ValueS4"]`?

Comment: ... just do that? The headers list is just a list of strings, you can put whatever you want in there. So you can iterate on your signals and add one item to the headers list for each signal. I don't rightly understand what the problemi is.

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Comment: I don't know what you could not know here. You can create a list, then assuming you have some sort of number of signals, add new stuff in it, e.g. `headers = ["name"]; for i in range(signals_count): headers.append(f'ValuesS{i}')`. Then you give that as the headers list to csv, and generate your rows properly.